# How can I Terminate Vector Input Using if statement in C++

Tags: c++

Does anybody have a simple solution to terminate a for loop that inputs values for a vector when a specific value is placed into the vector, but does not store that specified value into the vector?

I have created a random number generator that creates "n" unique values for a vector of size "n". However, when I run my code, the word "done" pops up and the program crashes.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
int i = 0;
vector<int> playerIndex;
vector<int> randGenNum;
vector<string> players;
vector<string> team1;
vector<string> team2;
vector<string> team3;
vector<string> team4;


cout << "Welcome to the Team Selector. \n" << endl;
cout << "A random team of two will be generated for you all." << endl;
cout << "When you are finished entering player names, enter the word \"done\". " << endl;
cout << "Enter the name of the players: \n" << endl;

for(string name; cin >> name;){
    players.push_back(name);

    if(name == "done"){
     players.erase(players.end() - 1);
     break;
    }else{
        playerIndex.push_back(i);
        i++;
    }

}

cout << "\n";
cout << "Player names: \n";

for(int a=0; a < players.size(); a++){
   cout << a + 1 << " - " << players[a] << endl;
}

srand(time(0));

int b =0;
int randNum;

while(b < players.size()){
    randNum = 1 +(rand()%players.size());                                               
    if(find(randGenNum.begin(), randGenNum.end(), randNum)!= randGenNum.end()){         
       while(find(randGenNum.begin(), randGenNum.end(), randNum)!= randGenNum.end()){   
            randNum = 1 +(rand()%players.size());                                       
       }
       randGenNum.push_back(randNum);            
        b++;                                   
    }else{
    randGenNum.push_back(randNum);              
    b++;                                        
    }
}


cout << "\n" <<"This is a test" << endl;
for (int c=0; c < players.size(); c++){
    cout << "Generated #: " << randGenNum[c] << endl;
}

int totalPlayers = players.size();
int firstPlayer = randGenNum[0];
int secondPlayer = randGenNum[1];
int thirdPlayer = randGenNum[2];
int fourthPlayer = randGenNum[3];
int fifthPlayer = randGenNum[4];

cout << "\n";
cout << "Team 1 is: " << players[firstPlayer] << " and "<< players[secondPlayer] << "\n" << endl;
cout << "Team 2 is: " << players[thirdPlayer] << " and " << players[fourthPlayer] << "\n" << endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about `if (name == "done") break;` **before** you push the name to the vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

`players.end() - 1` is not a valid iterator.

**Solutions 1:**

Check the item before adding it to the vector.

```
for(string name; cin >> name;) {
   if(name != "done")
   {
      players.push_back(name);
      playerIndex.push_back(i);
      i++;
   }
}
```

**Solutions 2:**

Use `std::vector::pop_back()`.

```
for(string name; cin >> name;){
   players.push_back(name);

   if(name == "done"){
      players.pop_back();
      break;
   }else{
      playerIndex.push_back(i);
      i++;
   }
}
```